# My top header looks different on single pages but is fine on the home page

Tags: php, css

For some reason, my top header looks different on single pages but is fine on the home page.
[my site](https://www.myccandbuilds.com/)

```
     <?PHP
   if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ):
                    ?>
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">CC AND BUILDS</a> </h1>
    <?php
    else :
                    ?>
    <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">CC AND BUILDS</a></p>
    <?php
    endif;
    ?>
```

any ideas?

Comment: You've made a few mistakes, one of them is hardcoding the logo URL, but making it a relative URL not an absolute URL, as well as making the HTML tags different, if you want them to look the same you should make them be the same

Comment: can you give me an example, please

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet you posted, it appears that your site's title will be wrapped in an `<h1>` tag on the home page (that's what the `if ( is_front_page() && is_home() )` code is checking for), and in a `<p>` tag in all other cases (eg, a single blog post's view).

Comment: yes but why does it look different style wise

Comment: That feels like a CSS question. What differences do you have in your stylesheets between the `h1` and `p` tags?

Comment: the rule comes from `h1 .top-cab, p .top-cab  {
 font-family: "Press Start", "cursive", "sans-serif";
 font-size: .3em;
}`

Comment: something is going on here that CSS should work